# Android Visualizer error only in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, visualizer

i've found one issue related with Visualizer that takes place only in Android 6.0 devices. Don't really know why it happens, so any kind of help would be appreciated. Here is the error stack:

```
AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -1
visualizers-JNI: Visualizer initCheck failed -3
Visualizer-JAVA: Error code -3 when initializing Visualizer.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
System.err: at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:218)
System.err:     at com.xxx.xxxx.customviews.visualizer.VisualizerView.link(VisualizerView.java:101)
```

and here is the code that causes it:

```
public void link(MediaPlayer player) {

    if (player == null) {

        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot link to null MediaPlayer");
    }

    Equalizer mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, player.getAudioSessionId());
    mEqualizer.setEnabled(true); // need to enable equalizer


    try {

        int aud = player.getAudioSessionId();
        **mVisualizer = new Visualizer(aud);**
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
        mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
        Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener captureListener = new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                updateVisualizer(bytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                updateVisualizerFFT(bytes);
            }
        };

        mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(captureListener, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, true);
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e) {       

        e.printStackTrace();        
    } 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the underlying component(s) needs some permissions that do not automatically get granted in 6.0. Goto AppInfo for this app; navigate to permissions; ensure all permissions that this app has requested has been granted.

Comment: This is the right answer. I'm still not familiarized with the new Permission system. Thanks =)

Comment: Also pls consult the document "requesting permissions at run time" in developer.android.com to understand how to handle permissions in M.

Comment: That's what i did. Thanks again =)

Comment: How do I "Goto AppInfo?"

Comment: @JellicleCat: Long press the app icon and context menus "App Info" and "Uninstall" should popup

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this permission in your Manifest as the Visualizer requires it.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>`

As this permission is 'dangerous' you also need to ask the user to grant the permission at runtime as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding to your permission list in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy for weeks...I was focusing on my `Visualizer` code, where the 6.0 permission system was the problem. I have tested this on 4.2.2, 5.0, and 6.0.1 on real devices. I still don't know why the permission dialog never comes up when I am testing the app on real devices. Also, manually turning on the `Microphone` permission solved the problem, in App Info settings.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                 {
                     requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 1);
        }
```